BLE SIG Environmental Sensing Service
I am working on a project which involves sensor data being sent over BLE. Approach is to use the BLE SIG Environmental Sensing Service(ESS). In the ESS found Temperature, Humidity characteristic but didn't see any characteristic for CO2. Is there any UUID available for CO2 sensor.

Looking at both the PDF and YAML from the Assigned Numbers on the Bluetooth site agree that can't see a UUID for Carbon Dioxide Concentration in the Environmental Sensing Service Permitted Characteristics.
The only mention of Carbon Dioxide is in the appearance categories:



Category (bits 15 to 6)
Subcatgeory (bits 5 to 0)
Value
Name




0x015
0x0A
0x054A
Carbon Dioxide Sensor



